# Observable collection changing wrt more than one collection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an observable collection Display Collection in view model. 
In view it is bound to itemsource of a list with custom view cell.

ViewModel :

```
public ObservableCollection<StatisticsData>DisplayCollection { get; set; } = null;

private ObservableCollection<StatisticsData> Collection1 = null;

private ObservableCollection<StatisticsData>Collection2 = null;

void somefn(string btnname){

if(btnname.equals("1"))
DisplayCollection=Collection1;
}

else
{
DisplayCollection = Collection2;
}
```

View.xaml

```
<listview ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayCollection}">
```

View.xaml.cs

```
View()
{
InitializeComponent();
ViewModel vm = new ViewMode();
this.BindingContext= vm;
}
```

On button click, the UI is not changing inspite of the displaycollection changing.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface an have a function like:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
 {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
 }
```

Then when the collection changes you have to call

```
OnPropertyChanged("nameOfTheCollection");
```

It could be in the set or wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged otherwise the XAML never knows that your collection has been updated.

If you're going to be using MVVM then I suggest you create a base view model:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
                                    [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    internal bool ProcPropertyChanged<T>(ref T currentValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertName = "")
    {
        return SetProperty(ref currentValue, newValue, propertName);
    }

    internal void ProcPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then in your all of your view model classes extend this base:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

Then whenever you update something you want to see in the XAML use one of the functions in the base class:

```
bool myBool
public bool MyBool
{
get { return myBool; }
set { SetProperty(ref myBool, value); }
}
```

For your case, whenever the collection changes when using this base view model you'd simply need to call: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayCollection));`